# What is implication of adding @Component to custom Spring Security filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-ldap

I have a custom Spring Security filter extending GenericFilterBean.

To do automatic dependency and bean creation I added a @Component annotation.

In my Security config I also register the filter like:

```
@Autowired
private RestAuthenticationFilter restAuthenticationFilter;

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter, LogoutFilter.class)
```

Everything works well except that my filter is called twice...
It seems Spring adds filters also automatically to standard filters.

What should be the best approach here?

**UPDATE**

@Dave is this what you mean? It seems to work.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationFilter restAuthenticationFilter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationSecurity applicationSecurity() {
        return new ApplicationSecurity();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(restAuthenticationFilter);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private RestAuthenticationFilter restAuthenticationFilter;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter, LogoutFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
                    .and()
                .requestCache()
                    .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It somehow feels nasty to explicitly disable the filter by declaring a FilterRegistrationBean @bean.

Comment: I think ideally a Filter's intent might be able to be inferred from a marker annotation (`@SecurityFilter`?) in conjunction with the `@Component` - ie - use me in the Security chain vs. use me in the standard filter chain.  I ran into a similar issue myself, because my filter didn't need any Bean resources I did not register it as a `@Bean`, just a security Filter programmatically.

Comment: A @SecurityFilter annotations sounds great! What do you think Dave? File a github issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to explicitly register the filter and mark it as "enabled=false" using the `FilterRegistrationBean` API. Then Spring Security will use it in its chain, but Boot will not try and register it as well.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'm trying to understand the answer... What you are basically saying is that Spring Boot is automatically adding the filter, and that I should register it as enabled=false to disable this behavior? I looked at FilterRegistrationBean apidocs but do not understand how to use enabled=false. Do yo maybe have some pointers or maube know some example?

Comment: I just noticed the RegistrationBean.setEnabled, I will try this.

Comment: Dave, see my updated question with code how I solved it. Is this the approach you meant?
On a side note, wouldn't it be easier to have application.property to disable auto registering servlets and filters? In most cases you don't add ny any custom servlets; mainly the Spring Dispatcher servlet and security filters.

Comment: Programming in properties files again? The dispatcher servlet and the security filter are the same as any other servlet and filters as far as the `ApplicationContext` is concerned, so I don't think an environment setting is really appropriate in this case.

Comment: The problem that I'm facing now with `setEnabled(false)` is that the `init` method for my custom filter is never called. How can I prevent the filter from being eagerly registered by Spring but still able to initialize when inserted in a spring security filter chain?